# How to explicitly set samesite=None on a flask response

Tags: python, flask, cookies, samesite

Due to changes arriving in Chrome during July, I need to modify my app to explicitly provide the SameSite=None key value.  This is due to the RFC treating the absence of this setting in a more impacting way than if it is present but set to None.

However on the set_cookie method, the samesite parameter is defaulted to None which results in it not being written into the set-cookie.  How can I force this into the set-cookie part of the response?

When I try to set the samesite=None with the following code

```
resp.set_cookie('abcid', 'Hello', domain=request_data.domain, path='/', samesite=None, max_age=63072000)
```

This does not show any SameSite detail in the returned set-cookie

> abcid=Hello; Domain=.localhost; Expires=Tue, 29-Jun-2021 22:34:02 GMT; Max-Age=63072000; Path=/

And if I try and explicitly set the value of Lax (which is one of the accepted values per rfc) as so

```
resp.set_cookie('abcid', "Hello", domain=request_data.domain, path='/', samesite="Lax", max_age=63072000)
```

I get back the set-cookie which explicitly has the SameSite=Lax setting

> abcid=Hello; Domain=.localhost; Expires=Tue, 29-Jun-2021 23:03:10 GMT; Max-Age=63072000; Path=/; SameSite=Lax

I have tried None, "None", and "" but these either crash the application or omit the SameSite in the resultant response.

Any help would be gratefully received

Comment: Have you tried `False`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and only just managed to try this but unfortunately the same result - No SameSite key is rendered when samesite parameter is set to False in the set_cookie method

Comment: Searching further it looks to be a bug in werkzeug that is the development web server.  The faulting line is in http.py 1168: if samesite not in ("Strict", "Lax", None):  (version 0.15.4).  If this is changed to add "None" in the in list it will render correctly.  Unfortunately this isn't a good option so I am going to AWS deploy to elastic beanstalk to see if the issue exists in live

Comment: Bug report listed here for it btw https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1549 and it looks as if the bug fix has been made and waiting for release

Answer (score 13):

Once [the fix to this issue](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1549) is
released, you will be able to use
[`set_cookie()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie)
like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    resp = make_response('Hello, World!');
    resp.set_cookie('same-site-cookie', 'foo', samesite='Lax');
    resp.set_cookie('cross-site-cookie', 'bar', samesite='Lax', secure=True);
    return resp
```

While you're waiting for the release, you can still
[set the header](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Headers.add)
explicitly:

```py
from flask import Flask, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    resp = make_response('Hello, World!');
    resp.set_cookie('same-site-cookie', 'foo', samesite='Lax');
    # Ensure you use "add" to not overwrite existing cookie headers
    resp.headers.add('Set-Cookie','cross-site-cookie=bar; SameSite=None; Secure')
    return resp
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following code to set cookies with `SameSite=None` until fix is released

```
from werkzeug.http import dump_cookie

# That's a workaround for explicitly setting SameSite to None
# Until the following fix is released: 
# https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1549
def set_cookie(response, *args, **kwargs):
    cookie = dump_cookie(*args, **kwargs)

    if 'samesite' in kwargs and kwargs['samesite'] is None:
        cookie = "{}; {}".format(cookie, b'SameSite=None'.decode('latin1'))

    response.headers.add(
        'Set-Cookie',
        cookie
    )
```

Comment: The latin-1 decoding is unnecessary. You can use `cookie = f'{cookie}; SameSite=None'`.